# Can I Install R libraries in databricks without reinstalling each time the cluster is turned on?

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to install R libraries (VIM and arrow), I have tried with the inits script and the global init script, also with the option to install libraries directly in the cluster but every time I turn on the cluster they are reinstalled and the problem is that exactly those two R libraries are taking about 17 min to install:

Using Global Init Scripts:

[image]

Using cluster libraries

[image]

Installation time:

[image]

**What can I do to reduce these installation times?**

Answer (score 2):

You are installing packages from http://cran.us.r-project.org.use try using the https://cloud.r-project.org instead; it's more reliable
Sometimes the package installer customizes things to the location where the package is installed.

As you mentioned you want to install the R libararies on cluster.
As per databricks You can use method of installing packages in R, such as `install.packages()` in the databricks notebooks

Explicitly set the installation directory to `/databricks/spark/R/lib`.
For example, with `install.packages(), run install.packages("pckg", lib="/databricks/spark/R/lib")`.

Packages installed in `/databricks/spark/R/lib` are shared across all notebooks on the cluster.

**Reference:**
[How do I install a package on just the driver for all R notebooks?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/notebooks-r-libraries#how-do-i-install-a-package-on-just-the-driver-for-all-r-notebooks)

I have tried the bleow approach:

```
%r
install.packages("VIM")

%r
install.packages("arrow")
install.packages("VIM", lib="/databricks/spark/R/lib")
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Install VIM package to /databricks/spark/R/lib**

```
%r
install.packages("VIM", lib="/databricks/spark/R/lib")
```

**Install arrow package to /databricks/spark/R/lib**

```
%r
install.packages("arrow", lib="/databricks/spark/R/lib")
```

[image]

[image]

This %r command tells Databricks to execute the following R code on the cluster, not just in the notebook.
This way, the packages will be installed on the cluster nodes.

In addition to this I have also tried Install the arrow package & VIM package from GitHub

```
%r
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("apache/arrow/r")
devtools::install_github("alexkowa/VIM")
```

The above code You are installing packages for the notebook environment:
Packages installed will only be accessible to the current notebook and spark jobs launched from this notebook.
These packages are automatically available on Spark workers.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but anyway every time I start the cluster I have to reinstall libraries again.  Is there no way to leave them permanently installed?

Comment: @Jean If you want to make the libraries persistent the better way would be the installing them directly on the cluster UI